# Bing still showing up in Windows 8 after being uninstalled

Tags: windows-8, firefox, internet-explorer, homepage

I have uninstalled Bing, i have supposedly rendered it useless by all kinds of methods but Bing still comes back every time i open firefox and internet explorer. And now i have MSN coming up as well. My google.com home page is virtually useless because it diverts to Bing. I have an HP Envy running Windows 8. It's brand new and it's driving me crazy. I have a desktop running Windows 7 and i have none of these problems. can anyone tell me a way to delete both Bing and MSN permanently from my laptop so google.com STAYS as my home page?

Comment: If you've changed your homepage to something other than Bing/MSN and they are getting set back again, *some* app/add-on for sure is resetting it since it can't happen automatically and the browser won't undo your changes either. If visiting Google diverts to Bing, you might want to scan your system for malware.

Comment: in firefox. type about:config in address bar and click Enter.  click i'll be careful. Then, search for bing. you will get a list of items containing keyword bing. right click on each of the items and click reset. restart the browser. it should work.